# Entropy and work

Tags: thermodynamics, work, entropy

Work done in an isentropic process does not cause dissipation but leads to change in temperature of a system. But temperature allows wider range kinetic energy to be accessible leading to more microstates. This should lead to increase in entropy, but this doesn't seem to happen here.
Does this mean that increase in entropy is compensated by something else? Or am I making some mistake here.

Comment: In the standard isentropic process, the volume decreased for the temperature to increase.

Comment: The decrease in volume decreases entropy

Comment: Ok. Is it equivalent to saying that microstates aren't affected by reversible mechanical energy.

Comment: @Alv The increase in entropy due to temperature increase equals the decrease in entropy due to volume decrease for a total change of zero

Comment: @BobD Ok I got confused from the graph of S v/s T.  But It is clear now.

Comment: @Alv just out of curiosity, what TS diagram were you looking at?

Comment: @BobD it was Temperature-Entropy graph in isentropic process. It was just a line parallel to temp axis.

Comment: @Alv Your looking at a constant entropy line that reflects the change in entropy due to the combination of temperature increase and volume increase.